# Performance of query from this schema

Tags: mysql, mariadb, index-tuning, where

Essentially all comments are stored in this schema (dbml)

```
table comments {
  commentID BINARY(16) [not null] //UUID
  post_date timestamp
  postID BINARY(16) [not null] //UUID
  has_reply bool [default: false]
  // replyTo either points to commentID, or null
  // Essentially won't be loaded as a 'root' comment
  reply_to varchar [default: null]
  comment_content varchar [not null]
  // dislikes will decrease, likes increase
  likes int [default: 0]
  visible bool [default: true]
}
```

As the user goes through the posts, essentially the database would be queried as following
`SELECT * FROM foo.comments WHERE postID = "ID of the post the USER is currently on" LIMIT 0, 20`

Because of this setup, I realized this table would grow quite large housing all the comments.
After a while (say ambitiously) 1 million comments are created.  How would mariaDB handle this? Would it be dreadfully slow, if so how should it be modeled?

**Will the WHERE clause save me from performance issues?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table?  Probably `commentID` is unique to each row??  If so, add `PRIMARY KEY(commentID)`.

For `WHERE postID = "..."`, you should add `INDEX(postID)`.  That will make *that* query fast even for a billion rows.

Read about "indexes" (aka, "keys").